# No figures when .md file is used as page with GitHub pages

Tags: html, plot, rstudio, markdown, github-pages

I am using GitHub pages for my [website](https://thomassie.de)!. I add new pages as md files, which nicely works when there are no figure included.

However, when I did some analyses in RStudio (.Rmd file) the final md file does not display any figure or leaflet object when used with GitHub pages. When I include the html file directly everything works nicely except for the fact that it does not look like the rest of my site (which I want, of course). I have to mention that I use an adapted version of the [beautiful-jekyll template](https://deanattali.com/beautiful-jekyll/)! by [Dean Attali](https://deanattali.com/aboutme/)!.

I was wondering why it is not working. Maybe it is due to an issue with some css file. Remember: When I load RStudio's html output everything is displayed as intended. [Here](https://github.com/thomassie/thomassie.github.io)! is a link to the respective GitHub repository.

I hope that there is someone out there having an answer to this.

Thanks!

Note: In case you cannot access the repository/files, you can download the files [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?id=E084CCF0B46EB2FB%21136&cid=E084CCF0B46EB2FB). It's the .Rmd as well as the output as .md and .html, and the .RData. As said before, including the .html works, but doesn't have the formatting according to my .css. .md fails in the way it doesn't show figures or leaflet objects, but the formatting is fine. [Have a look](http://thomassie.de/StormDataExploration/).

Comment: GitHub Pages uses Jekyll, which uses kramdown to render Markdown to HTML. AFAIK, kramdown does not include support for r-markdown. I expect the only way this will work is if you render to HTML locally.

Comment: Hey Waylan! Thanks for your comment. Actually, I write in R markdown in RStudio. The output files are an html and an md file. That is all done by RStudio. The point is that this md file is not showing any figures or leaflet maps when rendered to html. Text and code blocks work however...  =/

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a sample of the Markdown which isn't working as expected? Also, it would help to see the rendered HTML.

Comment: Added a note. See above...

Comment: I don't have time to go sort through your files. Please provide a single example in your question. -1

Comment: Well, you have the rendered .html and .md files. You can also find the original .Rmd file. You should be able to run the latter one to generate files by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, the issue with missing figures was solved.

- One has to be careful where to place the folder containing all figures. It has to have the same path as the .md files.
- Additionally, the embedding has to be changed in the .md file from `![](path/filename)` to `![filename](paths/filename)`.

That's it for the figures. Now I'm looking for a smart way of handling the leaflet objects.